Boosting for regression trees -- Explanation of the algorithm
I am reading Algorithm on Boosting for Regression Trees from the book "An introduction to statistical learning" by James et al. (2013) -- page 322. I am really struggling to understand the algorithm step by step.
What means "Set $\hat{f}(x)=0$ and $r_{i} = y_{i}$"? As far as I understand, $\hat{f}(x)$ is the predictor given $x$ value(s). But what model is used? Regression tree or linear regression? How make the latter equal to 0? I don't understand the first step, and therefore do not comprehend next steps.
Could someone guide me through each step of this process and provide a brief explanation for each one? Alternatively, if you could recommend another source for this information (any reading), that would be helpful.

